Am I minting nfts or SPL?
Hey guys im trying to mint directly in anchor a SPL token and by accident I think im minting nfts:
Here's my anchor call:
create_metadata_accounts_v3(
    CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
            metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata_account.to_account_info(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            mint_authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
            update_authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
            payer: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        },
    ),
    DataV2 {
        name: name.clone(),
        symbol: symbol.clone(),
        uri: uri.clone(),
        seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
        creators: None,
        collection: None,
        uses: None,
    },
    false, // Is mutable
    true,  // Update authority is signer
    None,  // Collection details
)?;

That mints and then the mint actually has this metadata ( extracted from solscan) :
{11 items
key:
4
updateAuthority:
"Bez3dNkekDtvCYkNcgNvLQeumkV6B7UBMqkjxztzNRtB"
mint:
"5AjU5aGPJYFd37oqK5rrHadoSpxMU3pqwzeo8NZAseMJ"
data:{5 items
name:
"Solany"
symbol:
"SOLANY"
uri:
"https://cf-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmdzqHXDD6EBic8Vzeayc5LyMxWd36ZcbvhrNWbQsG2JD9"
sellerFeeBasisPoints:
0
creators:
undefined
}
primarySaleHappened:
0
isMutable:
0
editionNonce:
255
tokenStandard:
1
collection:
undefined
uses:
undefined
type:
"metaplex"
}

However all the windows point for a collection name etc..
COmparing to the result I want to achieve it's quite different, here's an example of what I want to achieve:
Metadata on Solscan:
{8 items
key:
4
updateAuthority:
"TSLvdd1pWpHVjahSpsvCXUbgwsL3JAcvokwaKt1eokM"
mint:
"EbhvEvKas2nsnpiuAe6pVjBELM1HMHcAbBgVuKmnpump"
data:{4 items
name:
"Solany"
symbol:
"SOLANY"
uri:
"https://cf-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmdzqHXDD6EBic8Vzeayc5LyMxWd36ZcbvhrNWbQsG2JD9"
sellerFeeBasisPoints:
0
}
primarySaleHappened:
0
isMutable:
0
editionNonce:
255
tokenStandard:
2
}

Image of my token mint:

Image of what I want to achieve:

What am i missing here?

The difference between an regular token (fungible token) and an NFT (Non-fungible token) is the number of decimals. Note that in Solana, both are SPL tokens.
Typically decimals are set between 0-9, where 0 means an NFT, and above that, a regular SPL token which you want to create here.
I see that you are using create-token example from solana-developers/program-examples on GitHub. There, you can see the create_token_mint instruction's first parameter is _token_decimals, which is being used in the CreateTokenMint context below to set the decimals for mint_account that is being created.
You are most likely passing that first _token_decimals parameter as 0 when calling your instruction, which is leading to formation of an non-fungible token instead of a fungible token. Instead, pass it to whatever decimals you want your token to be, let's say, 9.
